# How do i handle time in of students one after another fast in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

So my friend and I developed an Attendance Monitoring System that uses RFID and SMS (broadband stick). The problem we were facing is that it takes probably 3-5 seconds before the next student could time in. What happens after a student times in:

1. Fetches info (name,grade/section,pic,name and number of guardian/parent)
2. Displays the info (name, grade/section,pic)
3. Sends an sms using the name and number of the guardian/parent
4. Saves the info and date/time as the student's attendance
5. Clears the displayed info

My friend tried multi threading but still takes a couple of time for all the process to finish.
I was hoping to re develop this in c# but I cant find a way to minimize the time it takes to process a student's time in.

Ps
We're only novices in programming. C# and VB were the only languages we know and few MySQL. We just can't find the right term to look for.

Comment: What is your data layer? DB? remote storage? files? do you close the connection for each student or keep it open? do you commit after each student? Please try to [1] Skip on step #4.  [2] Try get all stutend in once

Comment: You want to receive Asynchronously.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/mobilebroadband/run-new-sms-received-background-events

Comment: I'm not sure the problem is well specified - you seem to be complaining that you can only get one student checked in every 3 seconds, a process that includes putting a human through a door? bringing up their ID? having a security guard check it?. 3 seconds seems pretty reasonable as a minimum time for that, no? I think you need to better specify the real world process youre going through, the system spec and the mandatory timings

Comment: @AsfK read up on connection pooling

Comment: I guess you could just check that the student is "valid" (probably first step), and then process the rest of the steps in a queue, so out of process. Fetching a record from the database should be in the milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

So, you are looking for performance optimisation.

Switching from vb.net to c#.net will change nothing. Check CIL - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language

Everything is translated to the same intermediate language.

What you can try:

1. Use profilers to narrow down where your code lags: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/?view=vs-2019
2. Check the performance of any remote apis from which you are getting your data.
3. Check the performance of your database. Indexes on tables, carefully written queries and nice design, could bring the times down to milliseconds

On multithreading: This would help if your problem was processing power or if your code was blocking in the same thread. Depending on the technology stack, this could or could not be the case.

My guess is that your spend most of your time in round trips to apis and/or databases. When you optimize everything else, then you'll see if there is need for parallelism. Try using the async versions of the functions wherever possible and you'll achieve some inherent parallelism anyway.

Comment: If these info aren't always evolving, adding a cache logic would improve a lot on the overall response time, too.

Comment: Thank you for this. We'll try this 